# Is the following an open cover for the set $K = \{0\}\cup \{1/n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I know it has been asked to death on this site how to prove that $K = \{0\}\cup \{1/n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is compact. I would like to not be spoiled about the proof as IMO my question is tangential to a "show me the proof" question.

Let us assume that $K$ is compact. Then by definition any open cover $\{G_\alpha\}$ for $K$ contains a finite (in indices $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$) subcover. Let $a_n$ be a real number sequence defined by $a_k = \begin{cases}0: k = 0\\ \frac{1}{n}: k > 0\end{cases}, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{0+}$, and $G_k$ a sequence of open sets defined by $G_n = (a_{n} - \epsilon_n, a_{n-1} + \epsilon_n), n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\epsilon$ is allowed to depend on the index of the set in such a way that $a_{n+2} \notin G_n$, for all $n$ and $G_{i} \cap G_{j} = \varnothing$ for all $i > j + 1$. For example $G_1 = (1/2 - \epsilon_1, 1 + \epsilon_1), G_2 = (1/3 - \epsilon_2, 1/2 + \epsilon_2), G_3 = (1/4 - \epsilon_4, 1/3 + \epsilon_4), \dots$

Then if we allow momentarily $\infty$ to be an index, it follows that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}G_n = (0 - \epsilon_{\infty}, 1 + \epsilon_1)$. Thus $K \subset \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}G_n$. Since $K$ is compact $\{G_n\}$ must contain a finite subcover. But how can a finitely many open sets $G_n$ cover $K$? Is the $\{G_n\}$ constructed above a valid open cover for $K$ or is there some technical subtlety I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $\varepsilon_\infty$. And if you take, say, $\varepsilon_n=\frac1n$ ($n\in\Bbb N$), then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n=(0,2)$. In particular, $0\notin\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n$, and therefore $K\not\subset\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n$.